# Elasticsearch snaphots to s3

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have a elasticsearch 5.6.2 cluster with one master and two data nodes and I am using Kibana for visualizing . I want to enable automatic snapshots for the elasticsearch cluster to Amazon-s3 every 30mins. Can I Know How Can I accomplish it ..? There is no proper Documentation . I had also refered curator docs and I have a question, DO I need to configure that curator or on each node ...?

Please help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curator is an external process.

You must put it on one single machine. It can be a node or any other machine.
It will send REST requests to elasticsearch when needed.

Put in your crontab and that is going to be ok.

You can also call the SNAPSHOT endpoint manually from a shell script every 30 minutes and don’t use curator at all.

Elastic cloud does a backup every 30 minutes (in case you don’t want to manage the cluster yourself and have that kind of advanced features like also rolling upgrades, Kibana, security...)